# What is the best way to duplicate an element: only its type and attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have DOM element and I want to make a duplicate of it which contain none of the original's contents.

From: `<div class='cl' id='i'>Some text<p><a href="#">anchor</a>paragraph</p></div>`

produce: `<div class='cl' id='i'></div>`

But in an efficient way with javascript (or jQuery if it is much more elegant)

Does the most efficient solution require a `for` loop?

Comment: Don't forget to change the id of the clone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without jQuery, use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.cloneNode).

```
var newNode=oldNode.cloneNode(false);
```

Comment: The functionality of this function is pretty much perfect for my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and then set the `html` of the elemnt to nothing.

```
​$("#i").clone().html('')​​​​​​
```

Comment: Or I prefer `$("#i").clone().empty();` since the verb "empty" describes what is happening. @BertEvans - the way I read the doco page you linked to, it sounds like the parameters control whether event handlers are copied, not whether child elements are copied.

Comment: Yeah, .clone().empty() is exactly the kind of thing I don't like to do. It does unnecessary work and the fact that it does is also evident